# How can insert into a created table in JDBC after using if statement

Tags: java, jdbc

Hi guy's I need to know how can I (insert into) a created table cause I'm getting a lot of errors :

```
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,username,password);
        //query for the offer Validity
        String query = "SELECT chargingtime,CHARGINGPARTYNUMBER,SUBSCRIBERID,OFFERNAME,OFFERID,prepaidbalance,LIFECYCLE_DAYS,LVL,OPERATIONID FROM ncs_sub_unsub";

        try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                String SUBSCRIBERI = rs.getString("SUBSCRIBERID");
                String OFFERNAME = rs.getString("OFFERNAME");
                String OFFERID = rs.getString("OFFERID");
                String LIFECYCLE_DAYS = rs.getString("LIFECYCLE_DAYS");
                int LEVEL1 = rs.getInt("LVL");
                String CHARGINGPARTY =rs.getString("CHARGINGPARTYNUMBER");
                int OPERATIONID= rs.getInt("OPERATIONID");
                float prepaid_balance = rs.getFloat("PREPAIDBALANCE");
                LocalDate CHARGINGTIME1 = rs.getObject("CHARGINGTIME", LocalDate.class);
                LocalDate CHARGINGTIME7 = CHARGINGTIME1.plusDays(7);
                LocalDate CHARGINGTIME14 = CHARGINGTIME1.plusDays(14);
                //if the level is one , the time should be 7 days
                if(LEVEL1 == 1){
                    if((OPERATIONID == 4050001 && CHARGINGTIME1.isBefore(CHARGINGTIME7)) || CHARGINGTIME1.isEqual(CHARGINGTIME7)){
                     String q = String.valueOf(stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO aggregation VALUES (SUBSCRIBERI,CHARGINGPARTY,OPERATIONID,OFFERNAME,prepaid_balance,LIFECYCLE_DAYS,LEVEL1,'S')"));
                    } else if ((OPERATIONID == 4050018 && CHARGINGTIME7.isAfter(CHARGINGTIME1)) || CHARGINGTIME7.isEqual(CHARGINGTIME1)) {
                        String q = String.valueOf(stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO aggregation VALUES (SUBSCRIBERI,CHARGINGPARTY,OPERATIONID,OFFERNAME,prepaid_balance,LIFECYCLE_DAYS,LEVEL1,'U')"));
                    }else {
                        String q = String.valueOf(stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO aggregation VALUES (SUBSCRIBERI,CHARGINGPARTY,OPERATIONID,OFFERNAME,prepaid_balance,LIFECYCLE_DAYS,LEVEL1,'E')"));
                    }

                }

            }
            }// end of try
        catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        ViewTable();


    }
}
```

The error:

```
Caused by: Error : 984, Position : 111, Sql = INSERT INTO aggregation VALUES (SUBSCRIBERI,CHARGINGPARTY,OPERATIONID,OFFERNAME,prepaid_balance,LIFECYCLE_DAYS,LEVEL1,'U'), OriginalSql = INSERT INTO aggregation VALUES (SUBSCRIBERI,CHARGINGPARTY,OPERATIONID,OFFERNAME,prepaid_balance,LIFECYCLE_DAYS,LEVEL1,'U'), Error Msg = ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

Comment: Are you posting the [same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74086835/642706) under two identities?

Comment: unfortunately yes , cause i posted wrong title and caption sorry ...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Insert sql query is wrong.

I think you are trying to insert String values without '' and String values into float columns.

```
INSERT INTO aggregation VALUES (SUBSCRIBERI,CHARGINGPARTY,OPERATIONID,OFFERNAME,prepaid_balance,LIFECYCLE_DAYS,LEVEL1,'U')
```

This is not a valid sql query since prepaid_balance is not a number and SUBSCRIBERI is not a string (try 'SUBSCRIBERI' etc)

Answer (score 0):

> `stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO aggregation VALUES (SUBSCRIBERI,CHARGINGPARTY,OPERATIONID,OFFERNAME,prepaid_balance,LIFECYCLE_DAYS,LEVEL1,'U')"));`

This doesn't work. You can't use java variable names inside a string and expect the system to figure it out. That string is based *verbatim* to the SQL JDBC driver which is not capable of doing that sort of thing.

What you want is [A] not `executeUpdate`, it can't do this. You want `prepareStatement`. The statement would be something like:

```
"INSERT INTO aggregation VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,'U')"
```

and then you use the various `.setX` methods that PreparedStatement has to set the values: `.setString(1, SUBSCRIBERI);`, and so on for all the other question marks. Once you've done all that, you can run `.executeUpdate()` on the prepared statement object.

There are thousands of tutorials out on the web that show you how to use PreparedStatement here.